# Mathematics trouble in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, compilation

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class testqu {

        public static void main(String[] args) { 
          Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
          System.out.println("Enter the length of the first side of the triangle"); 
          double a = console.nextInt(); 
          System.out.println("Enter the length of the second side of the triangle"); 
          double b = console.nextInt(); 
          System.out.println("Enter the length of the third side of the triangle"); 
          double c = console.nextInt(); 


          if ((a*a) + (b*b) = (c*c))
            System.out.println("The triangle is a right triangle!");



} 
}
```

Assignment:

In a right triangle, the square of the length of the longest side is equal to the sum of the squares of the lengths of the other two sides.  Write a program that prompts the user to enter the lengths of three sides of a triangle, and then outputs a message indicating whether the triangle is a right triangle or not.  The program is to work correctly regardless to the order in which the lengths of the 3 sides are input.

My problems: code doesn't compile, found: variable, required: value

Also: I have no idea how to make it so the program would know if the triangle was right even if the sides were not given in order. Please help, I am a beginner having a lot of trouble with this assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the comparison operator `==` to compare values, not the assignment operator `=`, which can't assign a value to a value, only to a variable.  Change

```
if ((a*a) + (b*b) = (c*c))
```

to

```
if ((a*a) + (b*b) == (c*c))
```

Comment: Thank you! that made the code compile. Any idea how I can make it so the sides could be entered in any order and have it still recognize the right triangle?

Comment: Also check if `a*a + c*c == b*b` and if `b*b + c*c == a*a`.  You can use `||` to check if any of the 3 conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if ((a*a) + (b*b) = (c*c))
```

should be

```
if ((a*a) + (b*b) == (c*c))
```

Because one equals sign is assignment it takes two to perform a comparison.